# Replacing text in-place in an ASCII file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, str-replace

I'm encountering an issue using fileinput.input() and str.replace commands. I have a file with content A and content B (see image1.png). For each line that begins with`<part center_x=`, I need to replace the value of *center_x* and *center_y*. Towards that end, I wrote a python script which tries to do just that. To accomplish this I'm using Spyder 3.3.6 (from Ananconda3) and Python 3.7. The logic of the script is:

1. Create a copy of the file whose content will be replaced
2. Open that copy with fileinput.input()
3. Look for lines of text that begin with specific strings. If found, replace characters within that line (for example, if `<part center_x=`is found, I want python to replace values of *center_x=* and *center_y=*)
4. If the relevant line of text is not found, the script will not perform any operation other than rewriting that line of text into the copied file.

Unfortunately, str.replace isn't working the way I want it to - it either replaces characters with garbage or doesn't replace them at all. What ends up happening is shown in image2.png (the file on the RHS is the ORIGINAL file). Ideally, this is outcome that I want:

- Line 806: this line needs to read *center_x=2000* and *center_y=2000*
- Lines 808, 811, 814 and 817: *center_y* values for these lines need to be a constant value ( = 100), whereas values for *center_x* for these lines need to start at 100 and in increments of 100, end at 400. This behavior is reflected in lines 820, 823 and 826. I fail to understand why str.replace changes those characters correctly, but fails to do so for lines 808, 811, 814 and 817
- Line 814: value of *o_id* changes when I have not specifically asked Python to change it. I don't understand why this is happening. Please find my python code below.

Kindly let me know if I need to share anything else/ if I have not followed the best practices of Stack Overflow when asking questions

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Delete all generated variables before re-running this script using reset -f at the iPython console prompt

As long as the *.gtm file is a text file, this code is independent of GT version  
It depends on the following HTML-type tags 
-- <assembly_table>
-- <part_table> & </part_table>
-- <port_link_table> & </port_link_table>
-- <main size_x= 
-- <part center_x=
This code was built using Python 3.7 from the Anaconda 3 installation

Run this rearrangement code immediately after converting GEM3D to GTISE
I do not know how this code will affect files for which 
the map is already rearranged in a more or less structured form

if using Python 3.x, use 'range'
if using < Python 3.x, use 'xrange'

"""
## import block
import re, os, fileinput, sys
from shutil import copyfile

## User input area
fileName = "emptyTest.gtm"
pathToFile = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\koko\\Desktop")

# Check for file existence
if(os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathToFile, fileName))):

    src = os.path.join(pathToFile, fileName)
    dst = os.path.join(pathToFile, "deleteAfterUse_" + fileName + ".txt")
    copyfile(src, dst)

    finput = fileinput.FileInput(os.path.join(pathToFile, "deleteAfterUse_" + fileName + ".txt"), inplace=True)
    colFlag = 1
    rowFlag = 1
    for line in finput:            
        # Change the map size to be 2000 x 2000
        if(line.strip().startswith('<main size_x=')):
            mapSize_X = 2000
            mapSize_Y = mapSize_X
            temp1 = re.findall(r'\d+', line.strip())
            sys.stdout.write(line.replace(temp1[0], str(mapSize_X)).replace(temp1[1], str(mapSize_Y)))          
        #end

        elif(line.strip().startswith('<part center_x=')):
            temp2 = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            if colFlag%5 == 0:
                rowFlag = rowFlag + 1
                colFlag = 1
            #end
#            sys.stdout.write("ORG row  = {}; ORG column = {}\n".format(temp2[0], temp2[1]))
#            sys.stdout.write("Row  = {}; Column = {}\n".format(str(100*colFlag), str(100*rowFlag)))
            sys.stdout.write(line.replace(temp2[0], str(100*colFlag)).replace(temp2[1], str(100*rowFlag)))          
#            print("Location of {} = {} , {}".format(temp2[2], temp2[0], temp2[1]))      '
            colFlag = colFlag + 1
        #end        
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line)          
        #end
    #end
    finput.close()
```

[image: Screenshot of text file which is fed as input to Python script - content A is more important than content B. Hence needs modification]

[image: Difference between expected output (LHS) and input (RHS)]